# Cyvlfeat.vlad - 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, cython

I have installed cyvlfeat using `conda install cyvlfeat` ( from https://gsoc2016.wordpress.com/2016/08/19/cythonpython-wrapper-for-vlfeat-library-cyvlfeat-project-status/ ).
The problem is that when I run the following code:

```
from cyvlfeat import vlad
import numpy as np

N=1000
K=512
D=128

x = np.random.uniform(size=(D, N)).astype(np.float32)
means = np.random.uniform(size=(D, K)).astype(np.float32)
assignments = np.random.uniform(size=(K, N)).astype(np.float32)
enc = vlad(x, means, assignments)
```

error occures:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_vlad.py", line 11, in <module>
    enc = vlad(x, means, assignments)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable  ``` .
Thank you for your help!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from the blog post you're trying to use was never merged into the main project: https://github.com/menpo/cyvlfeat/pull/25

As you can see, currently `cyvfleat.vlad` is an empty module:

https://github.com/menpo/cyvlfeat/tree/master/cyvlfeat/vlad

Comment: Thank you! Is there any package that contains vlfeat or vlad for python?